# PHP Person Search with explode

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, explode, sqlsrv

I want to make a Search function in PHP and MSSQL with the SQLSRV Driver.

I only have one search input field on the page.
I want to search for persons in my table called "Persons" and the following columns: SSN, Firstname, Lastname

The problem is that one person could have one or more middelnames in the Firstname column.

I want also to search on single strings like: Only the firstname or only the middelname(s) or the Lastname.

How can I do this? Should I use the explode function in PHP?

Comment: Unless to rework your data model, you will end up with a very slow search, because at some point you will have to do string operations on your entire dataset.

Comment: Why that? Also if I use explode to change the LIKE queries

Comment: You just said your firstname column might contain "John Joe Jack James Joaquin". If you want to search only the middlenames, you would have to cut away "John ". In all rows. Obviously you could do a `LIKE '%James%'` and afterwards check for rows where that's not the first name in that column...but that would just be slow as well.

Comment: What about a extra column called "keywords" where i have name, middelname(s) and lastname following by a comma?

Comment: Hmm I need to search like: [firstname] [middelname] [lastname] OR [firstname] [lastname] OR [firstname] OR [lastname] OR [middelname]

Comment: What about a column called `middlename` to split up firstname and middlenames? Do you realize that your DBMS can't execute PHP code? And the DBMS should be the one to do the searching. Messing around with the query result in PHP afterwards is usually the worst possible approach.

Comment: I know the PHP code is executed by the iis webserver (fastcgi).

Comment: How should my query look like then if i have a column called middelname

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to build a search index.

In the following I assume your `persons` table looks like this:

```
  | person_id | firstname | lastname | ssn |
```

To be able to build a search index, you'll need a `person_searchindex` table for that:

```
  | person_id | search_term |
```

You could then use something like this: (It's just a very first sketch.)

```
<?php
function addTermToSearchIndex($person_id, $term)
{
    performQuery("INSERT INTO person_searchindex (person_id, search_term)
                  VALUES (" . (int)$person_id . ", ".
                  "\"" . escapeForQuery($term) . "\");");
}

function buildSearchIndexForPerson($person_id, $firstname, $lastname, $ssn)
{
    $firstnames = explode(" ", $firstname);
    foreach($firstnames => $name)
    {
        addTermToSearchIndex($person_id, $name);
    }

    $lastnames = explode(" ", $lastname);
    foreach($lastnames => $name)
    {
        addTermToSearchIndex($person_id, $name);
    }

    addTermToSearchIndex("$ssn");
}

function deleteSearchIndexForPerson($person_id)
{
    performQuery("DELETE FROM person_searchindex WHERE person_id = " . (int)$person_id . ";");
}

function rebuildSearchIndexForPerson($person_id, $firstname, $lastname, $ssn)
{
    deleteSearchIndexForPerson($person_id);
    buildSearchIndexForPerson($person_id, $firstname, $lastname, $ssn);
}

function rebuildSearchIndex()
{
    performQuery("DELETE FROM person_searchindex;");
    $result = performQuery("SELECT * FROM persons;");
    while($row = getRow($result))
    {
         buildSearchIndexForPerson($ow["person_id"], $row["firstname"], $row["lastname"], $row["ssn"]);
    }
}

function search($searchterm)
{
     $sqlcond = "FALSE";

     $terms = explode(" ", $searchterm);
     foreach($terms => $term)
     {
         $sqlcond .= " OR s.search_term LIKE \"%" . escapeForQuery($term) . "%\"";
     }

     return performQuery("SELECT p.person_id, p.firstname, p.lastname, p.ssn FROM persons AS p LEFT JOIN person_searchindex AS s ON p.person_id = s.person_id WHERE $sqlcond;");
}

?>
```

Add a call to the method `rebuildSearchIndexForPerson()` whenever you add or change a person row. Add a call to the method `deleteSearchIndexForPerson()` whenever you delete a person row. The first time you'll ever want to search something, you'll have to call `rebuildSearchIndex()` to create the search index for your old person rows. After that, you'll be able to use the `search()` function.

As I said, it's just a very first sketch. For example, you'll have to change the methods `performQuery`, `escapeForQuery` and `getRow` to what you'll actually use. Also, the quality of the php code is not particularily good. But the picture of how it works should get clear.